# Android - Programmatic scrolling of TabWidget

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, tabwidget

I have a `TabWidget` nested within a `HorizontalScrollView`.  I am programmatically setting the active/current tab (which I have no problem doing).  My problem is, the `TabWidget` is not scrolling to show thenewly active tab.

**Example** - I have 9 tabs, only 3 are shown at any given time (so think 3 'pages' of tabs).  I am on tab 1 (page 1).  I programmatically set the current tab to tab 8 (page 3).  The tab content switches properly (ie, I now see the contents of tab 8), however, the tabs up at the top still show tabs 1, 2, and 3.  If I manually scroll over to the right, I will see tab 8 (properly highlighted).  I want to automatically scroll the `TabWidget` so that the currently active tab is shown.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** example source:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String tag;

        /* logic to populate tag from intent*/

        /* reason for this is because I know the tag of the tab I need, 
           not the index num. of tab */
        getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(tag);
        int i = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();

        getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(i);
        getTabWidget().focusCurrentTab(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must both focusCurrentTab(int i) and setCurrentTab(int i). focusCurrentTab(i) will focus the UI of the TabWidget to the ith tab (what you want), and, as you already know, setCurrentTab(i) will focus the actual content of the ith tab in the main View.

For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#focusCurrentTab(int)

EDIT:

My answer was incorrect. This is the correct one (that the the poster found out themself):

It turns out that the TabWidget views had focusableInTouchMode set to false. As per View.java documentation:

A view will not actually take focus if it is not focusable ({@link #isFocusable} 
returns false), or if it is focusable and it is not focusable in touch mode 
({@link #isFocusableInTouchMode}) while the device is in touch mode.
To correct the problem I iterated over the TabWidget views and set them focusable in touch mode:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

Comment: @Vinay I am having *some* success with that (as in maybe 1 out of 10 times).  Since it is so sparadic, it leads me to believe that perhaps there is a race condition/timing/async issue.   Basically at the `TabHost` level, i call setCurrentTabByTag(tag), then say i = getCurrentTab().  Then on the `TabWidget`, I call setCurrentTab(i) and focusCurrentTab(i).  Any insight?

Comment: What exactly is happening when it doesn't work? Like does it set it to some tab that's just ridiculously far away from the tab you want? Is there a pattern in the way it messes up? Why not offer up the relevant code. That's probably the easiest way for me to see what could be going wrong.

Comment: @Vinay I edited original post to include code.  I apologize for not being more clear by what I mean by **some** sucess, as I was in a hurry earlier.  by **some** success I mean that sometimes the horizontally scrolling tabbar scrolls to the newly current tab, and other times, the tab will not move to reflect the newly selected tab.  The `framelayout` content correctly switches and the current tab is correctly selected/highlighted, however, sometimes the `tabhost` will 'scroll' to show the current tab, and other times it will not move.

Comment: It seems like you're setting the current tab twice. I'm not really sure why that would make it mess up, but that might be the case here. So let's try something. Try commenting out "getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(i);" and see what happens. If that doesn't make it work the way you want, uncomment that part out and then comment out "getTabWidget().focusCurrentTab(i);". Get back to me with the results of that endeavor. I'm curious why this isn't working now.

Comment: @Vinay no luck with either ... Also, examining TabHost.java and following the method calls, it looks like setCurrentTabByTag(index) calls the individual TabWidgets focusCurrentTab, so theoretically I shouldn't even have to make that call (focusCurrentTab in turn also calls setCurrentTab(index) so there are **MANY** repeated steps in this small amount of code).  End result, TabHost/TabWidgets still not scrolling to show the new current tab when programatically setting a new tab.  **NOTE** this is being done in a TabActivity (as can be gathered by the API calls), I will try manually in morn.

Comment: Yes I realized that as well. That is my fault for not referencing the documentation before I opened my big mouth. :-) (Or, rather, begin typing in this case haha.) I will think on this.

Comment: @Vinay just as an aside, however, I get 0% success when I just call **just** setCurrentTabByTag() .. that call alone never changes the tabs.  Again, I have to do some refactoring but I am going to create the tabs manually, hopefully I will have better success that way.

Comment: Damn well that explains why the second block of code doesn't work, since "i" is obviously never set up correctly. Are you sure your TabHost is set up correctly? If you don't mind, share the code where you set up your TabHost, whether or not you did it in a programmatic approach or in XML.

Comment: spent all day today working on setting up debugging (had no luck in eclipse, I installed android source, but when it would debug, the line numbers would be off, etc).  I had to eventually go to IntelliJ to get Java and Android debugging to work properly.  Anyways, once that was set up properly, I was actually able to debug the code and see that it was failing View.requestFocus().  Turns out the `TabWidget` views did not have setFocusableInTouchMode set to true, so when they were requesting focus, it would fail.   Thanks a ton for your help Vinay!

Comment: Haha no problem! I'm glad you figured it out though! So mark your own answer with the check mark and close this issue up. It will help people from realizing their same mistake in the future. ;-) Haha I'm actually kinda relieved as weird as that sounds. I COULDN'T figure out why you were not getting the expected results. Good luck with the rest of your Android coding!

Comment: Haha I meant mark your answer as the correct one. I didn't really help you. :-P I'll change mine to match yours I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

set to TabHost next OnTabChangeListener:

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(final String tag) {
    View tabView = tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
    int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft() - (tabsHorizontalScrollView.getWidth() - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
    tabsHorizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `TabWidget` views had focusableInTouchMode set to false.  As per View.java documentation:

```
A view will not actually take focus if it is not focusable ({@link #isFocusable} 
returns false), or if it is focusable and it is not focusable in touch mode 
({@link #isFocusableInTouchMode}) while the device is in touch mode.
```

To correct the problem I iterated over the `TabWidget` views and set them focusable in touch mode:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

Comment: I added the the tab widget inside the horizontal scroll view after this logic tab widget focus is working fine .but when try to scroll  tab widget get selected how to avoid this issue please suggest.