# TabHost in ScrollView, scroll to tab when selected

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, android-tabhost, horizontalscrollview

I have a TabHost inside a HorizontalScrollView that can sometimes have more than 20 tabs. On every tab activity, I can press a "next" button that instructs the TabHost to move to the next tab. The problem is, I cannot get the Scrollview to scroll to a selected tab if it is off screen.

Could someone tell me how this can be done?

Comment: Have you tried using `scrollView.scrollTo(int x, int y)` and specifying the x-coordinate of the tab you want to scroll to?

Comment: Actually no, but I figured that would be the right way to do it. My problem with that is how to find the x-coordinate of the tab?

Comment: did you succeed solving this issue ? i wonder what's the best way to do it.

Comment: never mind . found one by myself , and posted about it .

Answer (score 3):

you must "wrap" TabWidget in xml into   HorizontalScrollView:

....

```
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:fillViewport="true"
                          android:scrollbars="none"
                          android:id="@+id/tabsHorizontalScrollView">

        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

....

and set to TabHost TabHost.OnTabChangeListener

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(final String tag) {
    View tabView = tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
    int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft() - (tabsHorizontalScrollView.getWidth() - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
    tabsHorizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

got a working solution :

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(final String tag) {
    final int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    final View tabView = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(pos);
    final int[] locationOnScreen= new int[2];
    tabView.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);
    mtabsHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(locationOnScreen[0], 0);
}
```

Comment: it will not work with different tab sizes. also not efficient. it doesn't work on all scenarios.

Comment: @Krups not efficient in which way? which scenarios don't work? this was answered a very long time ago. I don't even remember what it does...

Answer (score 1):

Better and smoother way of doing this is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6131550/2511775

Do this for when you setup your tabs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

Comment: it won't work when scrollview size is larger than screen.